# How to use `create` instead of `FactoryGirl.create` on rails console

Tags: rspec-rails

For rails 3, rspec 2.6

I am able to use `create` instead of `FactoryGirl.create` in Rspec.

While verifying the working of factories, every time there is need to append `FactotyGirl` before `create`, which is taking more time in console.

Please provide a feedback, how we can use 'create'  in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use below in console:

`include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods`